# searchResultsController with a UITableViewController hides the navigation bar, how to prevent it?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

When I assign a TableViewController as the constructor for UISearchController, when the table is loaded, it hides the navigation bar (that includes title and search bar). How can I make it, so it doesn't hide it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureNavigationItem()
    }
}

extension ViewController {

    private func configureNavigationItem() {
        let resultsController =  UITableViewController(style: .plain)
        navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
}
```

[Initial Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmhpr.png)

[image]

[Tap Any Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQjNc.png)

[image]

Comment: Full Source Code: https://github.com/MartinChavez/NavBarHides, More information:

- Swift 4
- Xcode 9
- iOS 11

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer:

definesPresentationContext = true

as in:

```
private func configureNavigationItem() {
    let resultsController =  UITableViewController(style: .plain)
    navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    **definesPresentationContext = true**
}
```